# Propper way of creating a mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

What would be the correct way of building a sql query, in this scenario:

```
$data = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");

foreach ($data as $row) {
   $data2 = $db->one("SELECT amount FROM cart WHERE id = " . $row['id']);
   echo $row['name'] . '<br>';
   echo $data2['amount'] . '<br>';

}
```

In the above example, if I have 500 users, would that equal to 500 database calls?
Or should I use single query like:

```
  $data = $db->query("SELECT *" 
  . "\n (SELECT SUM(amount) FROM cart WHERE user.id = cart.user_id) as total" 
  . "\n FROM users";
```

Are there any advantages or disadvantages between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the following statement:

```
select
    u.name,
    sum(a.amount) as total
from users u
inner join cart a on u.id = a.id
group by
    u.name
```

This will give you the data in one shot. Assuming you have an index on cart's user id (I assume the column is named id) and users table's primary key is id, your data extraction is likely to be really fast. So the advantage is speed and a single query hit on the database.

The disadvantage of the former method in your question is that if you have 1000 users, amount from cart table will be extracted once for every 1000 users. If your PHP script is running on a different server from MySQL server, 1000 query text will go across the network and 1000 resultsets will be returned over the network. Such task takes more time and adds just a little more work on the database's side. Compare this with attempting to go to grocery store once for every product you want to buy. It is obviously inefficient to go from home to the store and buy eggs, drop them home, go again and buy apples, drop them home ...To make the process efficient, we get a cart-load of stuff from the grocery store in one shot. It's the same concept here.

When someone changes the specifications and asks you to get amount for only those users whose last name is Anderson, the first method in your question will require modification to the `select ... from users where last_name = 'Anderson'` and then get amount one by one for each record. Compare that with the single query in this answer and the answer from Kris, the same `where` clause would have to be added to the query and the results will be obtained in one-shot query.

Answer (score 0):

Like you say, the first method would indeed result in 500 database calls, so your second method is better.
However a better query may be

`SELECT *, SUM(c.amount) FROM users u JOIN cart c ON c.user_id = u.id GROUP BY u.id`